# How to change minor radius of a torus in blender 2.8

Tags: mesh

I cannot find the way to change the minor radius in blender 2.8.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In Blender 2.8 after adding the torus (or any primitive) a notification will pop up in the bottom left corner of the 3D View.

[image]

After pressing it, a list of options will appear, including the *minor radius*.

Alternatively, you can use shrink/fatten in edit mode (<kbd>ALT</kbd> + <kbd>S</kbd>).

Comment: Same with Blender Version 2.79